# Django pagination data is not serializable

Tags: ajax, django, pagination

I am trying to implement endless pagination using ajax post request.

My ajax query:

```
var product_id = {{product_id|safe}};
var category_id = {{category_id|safe}};
var subcategory_id = {{subcategory_id|safe}};
var ajax_type = {{ajax_type|safe}};
var url_name = {{url_name|safe}};
var page_no = {{page_no|safe}};
$.ajax({
    url : url_name,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    data : {action:ajax_type,
            product_id:product_id,
            category_id:category_id,
            subcategory_id:subcategory_id,
            page_no:page_no},

   success : function(response) {
       var new_products_list = response.products;
       page_no = response.page;
       .....
```

My view :

```
category_id = request.POST.get('category_id')
subcategory_id = request.POST.get('subcategory_id')
page = int(request.POST.get('page_no'))
product_data = Products().fetchProducts(category_id, subcategory_id)
paginator = Paginator(product_data, 12)
products = paginator.page(page)
print products
page = page + 1
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'products':products,'page':page}), content_type='application/json')
```

What i am trying to do is pass some variable including the url to html view. When the html loads an ajax call is sent to django view to fetch some products data. I can access all the variable passed from ajax in my django view.

Now when i paginate the data and print it using `print products` it print `<Page 1 of 1>` and when i pass the response through HttpResponse back to ajax, it gives error that `<Page 1 of 1> is not JSON serializable`. What i am doing wrong? How to pass the paginated data back to ajax function as response?

Also what could be the write way to paginate data using ajax?

Comment: Does `JsonResponse({'products':products,'page':page})` fix the issue?

Comment: No it didn't worked but i got a work around.

Comment: Any update on this ?